# Are stream listeners automatically removed when the stream is destroyed

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, listener

I am unsure if I should clean up a listener on a stream in node when I destroy the stream - it seems like it should be done automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unsure if I should clean up a listener on a stream in node when I destroy the stream

You do not need to clean up listeners on a stream that is finished.  Once the stream is finished and it goes out of scope or you clean up any references to the stream, then it will become eligible for garbage collection because there will no longer be any code that can reach that stream object and there will be no outstanding asynchronous operations that could trigger any more events.

It's important to understand that your listeners do not prevent the object from being garbage collected.  So, you don't need to clean them up in order for the object to become eligible for garbage collection.  Garbage collection is only about active code (timers, asynchronous operations, or code that has direct references to your object) that can still reach the object.

So, with no active references to the stream, the finished stream object and your listeners will all be garbage collected (and thus cleaned up automatically by the system).  You do not need to manually clean them up.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. If you destroy stream in node js callbacks will still be linked to a stream object.

Try to do this and look to the console:

```
const Readable = require("stream").Readable;
const s = new Readable();

s.onClose = () => console.log;
s.onPipeEnd = () => console.log;
s.destroy();

console.log(String(s.onClose));
console.log(String(s.onPipeEnd));
```

Comment: This isn't really what the OP was asking.  They are asking about ***listeners*** such as `s.on('close', someFunction)`.  Your `console.log()` statements are looking at ***methods***, not listeners.  Plus, when the whole object becomes eligible for garbage collection, the object and all those properties will be cleaned up just fine.

Comment: @jfriend00 But why if I add `process.on('close')` listener node says there are 11 not closed listeners during next script run (when new process is created)? Looks like if we have close listener we need to clear it or at least clear when process exited because of error?

Comment: @Rantiev - We can't help you with that without seeing your code.  You would need to write your own question and show your code.  That particular error you refer to usually means that you're "leaking" listeners which means you're adding listeners in some event driven thing and thus they accumulate and you have more than 11 listeners for the same event.  That is not always from an actual bug, but usually, it is an implementation mistake - thus the warning.  If you need further help, please write your own question and show your relevant code.